# MQQueueConnectionFactory - failed to instanciate while executing standalone jar

Tags: java, ibm-mq

Below is the code for IBM MQ :-

```
CfQueueSender queueSender = new CfQueueSender("send", MQConfigFile, jksFile);
queueSender.setHostName(hostName);
queueSender.setPortNumber(portNumber);
queueSender.setQueueManager(queueManager);
queueSender.setChannelName(channelName);
queueSender.setChannelIdentifier(channelIdentifier);
queueSender.sendNewAmendmentCancel(BEMRTMessage, numberOfMessagesToPush);




public void sendNewAmendmentCancel(String message, int numberOfMessagesToPush) throws Exception {
        MQQueueConnectionFactory cf = new MQQueueConnectionFactory();
        ......
}
```

While the above program runs via intelij all works fine but when tried via standalone jar below is the errors:-

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsFactoryFactoryImpl.getInstance(JmsFactoryFactoryImpl.java:170)
        at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.admin.JmsConnectionFactoryImpl.setProviderFactory(JmsConnectionFactoryImpl.java:167)
        at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQConnectionFactory.<init>(MQConnectionFactory.java:271)
        at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory.<init>(MQQueueConnectionFactory.java:72)
        at Runner.CfQueueSender.sendNewAmendmentCancel(CfQueueSender.java:42)
        at Runner.SMSListenerUtility.main(SMSListenerUtility.java:22)
```

IBM Traces :-

```
     WorkQueueMananger Contents
                           --------------------------

|   Maintain ThreadPool size     :-  false
|   Maximum ThreadPool size      :-  -1
|   ThreadPool inactive timeout  :-  0
|   unavailable -                :-  com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.CSIException: JMSCS0002

                       Stack trace
                                  -----------

Stack trace to show the location of the FFST call
|   FFST Location  :-  java.lang.Exception
|       at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.trace.Trace.getCurrentPosition(Trace.java:2146)
|       at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.trace.Trace.createFFSTString(Trace.java:2056)
|       at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.trace.Trace.ffstInternal(Trace.java:1938)
|       at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.trace.Trace.ffst(Trace.java:1739)
|       at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.nls.PINLSServices.createException(PINLSServices.java:112)
|       at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.nls.NLSServices.createException(NLSServices.java:226)
|       at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsErrorUtils.createException(JmsErrorUtils.java:126)
|       at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsFactoryFactoryImpl.getInstance(JmsFactoryFactoryImpl.java:168)
|       at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.admin.JmsConnectionFactoryImpl.setProviderFactory(JmsConnectionFactoryImpl.java:167)
|       at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQConnectionFactory.<init>(MQConnectionFactory.java:271)
|       at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory.<init>(MQQueueConnectionFactory.java:72)
|       at Runner.CfQueueSender.sendNewAmendmentCancel(CfQueueSender.java:42)
|       at Runner.SMSListenerUtility.main(SMSListenerUtility.java:22)
|
```

IBM MQ jars:-

[image]

Comment: What version of IBM MQ jars are you using.  Make sure you do not have a mix.  Best to use only com.ibm.mq.allclient.jar.

Comment: Can you turn on trace and share the last few lines of trace output, just before the NPE happens? See [Collecting an IBM MQ classes for JMS trace by using a Java system property](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.3?topic=tmcja-collecting-mq-classes-jms-trace-by-using-java-system-property).

Answer (score 0):

If it works in inteliji, but not as a standalone jar, that would indicate that the contents of the standalone jar are incorrect, and not the same as the inteliji environment.

Check your build dependencies, because that is where the error is.

As the comments to your question infer, the exception stack indicates a class / jar mismatch.  A trace, as recommended by Daniel, will tell you which jar file is being used.